# How to load object from route parameter using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I'm using react-router-redux and I have a route like this

```
<Route path="/user/:userId" components={{ body: UserMaintenance }} />
```

Whats the recommended way to load user object corresponding to the userId parameter in the route?

My thoughts (I'm new to react & redux) would be to use the userId parameter in the UserMaintenance `componentWillReceiveProps` method and dispatch a `FETCH_USER` action to the store which will load into `state.currentUser`. The UserMaintenance component would then update when the currentUser parameter is updated as a result of the action.

Comment: Your proposition will work fine! You could also use the `onEnter` hook from the specific route: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

Comment: Cheers, looks good as mentioned below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you must decide if you want your URL to be the source of truth for the userId (I'd suggest so).

Then you know that whenever the URL/route changes, and at no other time, you will dispatch `FETCH_USER`.

To change user from elsewhere within the app you just `browserHistory.push('/user/1234')` and know that the change in URL will trigger an update to the store.

If you're happy with that, just dispatch the action in the route:

```
<Route
  path="/user/:userId"
  components={{ body: UserMaintenance }}
  onEnter={state => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: ACTIONS.FETCH_USER,
      key: state.params.userId,
    });
  }}
/>
```

If you're following this logic, you might not need `react-router-redux`.

Interesting comments from the author of redux [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722584/how-to-sync-redux-state-and-url-hash-tag-params/36749963).

Comment: Thanks, nice and simple. Indeed interesting comments in that link.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to move that logic to `Container Component` that `connects` `UserMainenance` to your `redux store`

This would help you to separate data layer from `Presentational Component` that should not know anything about how to get data to render. It only needs to know how to render that data.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchUser} from './actions';
import UserMaintenance from './UserMaintenance';

class UserContainer extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const {fetchUser, userId} = this.props;
    fetchUser(userId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserMaintenance {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  userId: ownProps.params.userId
  user: state.user,

});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, {fetchUser}
)(UserContainer);
```

Assuming that you have `fetchUser` actionCreator.

I strongly recommend you to watch [Browse the Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux course](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux) by Dan Abramov (creator of Redux) on https://egghead.io. Its free and covers this topic very well.

Comment: Thanks. I did watch those as one of the first steps learning it all but will be worth going back over it soon now that I've actually been using it.