# Recommended approach to deep linking using redux and react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am building a web app using React (15.3.0), Redux (3.5.2) and react-router (2.6.1). I include the versions as I've seen a few related posts but they reference old versions of these libraries.

I have some state that I would like to persist on the URL so that the user can deep link to it. By deep linking, I mean that a user can link directly to a state of a page. I have various pages in my app, each page has a separate reducer, the state for each page should persist between pages.

I've read Dan Abramov's recommended approach: [How to sync Redux state and url hash tag params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722584/how-to-sync-redux-state-and-url-hash-tag-params/36749963#36749963)
Which seems ok, apart from persisting state between pages.

An example scenario:

1. User lands on page one: `/page1`
2. User interacts with the page causing state to be saved in the URL: `/page1?state={...}`
3. User goes to page 2: `/page2`
4. User interacts with page 2: `/page2?state={...}`
5. User links to page 1, expecting to see that page as they left it. Problem! How do we recover the state from page 1?

I've looked at react-router-redux, but I can't tell if it does what I need it to?

Is there a common approach to this problem? If so what is it? If not, can you suggest an approach?

Comment: why do you want save state in url ?

Comment: @Fantasim so that the user can share the link enabling another user to view that page in the same state.

Comment: So why do not you parses the URL in componentWillMount on main component about Page1 and you create an action to send data to the reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there is more than one answer to this; you just need to pick one and implement it.

If it were me, I would do this:

1. Use the redux store as the single source of truth for state
2. Subscribe to the store in some way (perhaps a redux middleware) and update the url params when the relevant state for page1 changes
3. If a user visits `/page1`, use the stored state (I'm assuming state will need to be synced to a server to be able to store/recover it).
4. If a user visits `/page1?state={...}`, either a) merge the URL state into the stored/recovered state or b) skip recovering and use the URL directly.

I would even go further and NOT sync the state to the url, since that seems like wasted effort (unless users are relying on bookmarking a page). Just render a React component saying "Share this URL" and have it render a URL with proper query params.

Comment: That's the solution I ended up with as well apart from I used `store.subscribe` instead of a middleware and did sync the store with url. Thanks!