# Redux & React Router: Combing dispatch and navigation (history.push)

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm a bit clueless as to how to use React Router's `history.push('/route')` with `Redux`.

In other words, if you connect a component with Redux's `mapDispatchToProps`, how do you put `history.push('/route')` that is supposed to be fired after dispatching a certain action?

To clarify the issue, here is a snippet of my experimentation...

```
class PostContainer extends React.Component {

    handleSubmit(data) {
        return this.props.addPost(data);
    }

    render() {
        return (<Post onSubmit={data=> this.handleSubmit(data)}/>);
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {    
        addPost: (data) => {
            dispatch(addPost(data)).data.then((result) => {
                dispatch(addPostFulfilled(result.data));

                //How do you call the following function?
                this.props.history.push('/posts')
            }).catch((error) => {
                dispatch(addPostRejected());
            });
        },      
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostContainer);
```

As you can see, as soon as a post is added into Redux's state through `addPostFulfilled`, the page needs to move to `/posts` via history.push.

According to Redux's doc, containers are made for updating states (as well as fetching data). So, dumb components are not supposed to put anything like `history.push`.

What would be a better approach than the code above?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either user react-router-redux (require an initial set up) and dispatch your action from action creators

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
class PostContainer extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(data) {
    return this.props.addPost(data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Post onSubmit={data=> this.handleSubmit(data)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {    
    addPost: (data) => {
      dispatch(addPost(data)).data.then((result) => {
        dispatch(addPostFulfilled(result.data));

        //How do you call the following function?
        dispatch(push('/posts'));
      }).catch((error) => {
        dispatch(addPostRejected());
      });
    },      
  }
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostContainer);
```

or just pass push as a "done callback".

```
class PostContainer extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(data, done) {
    return this.props.addPost(data, done);
  }

  render() {
    const { push } = this.props.history;
    return (
      <div>
        <Post onSubmit={data=> this.handleSubmit(data, push)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {    
    addPost: (data, done) => {
      dispatch(addPost(data)).data.then((result) => {
        dispatch(addPostFulfilled(result.data));

        //How do you call the following function?
        done('/posts')
      }).catch((error) => {
        dispatch(addPostRejected());
      });
    },      
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostContainer);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. So, would it be acceptable to have something other than Redux's actions inside `mapDispatchToProps`? Your code works perfectly fine, but I still feel a bit awkward to see `done('/posts')` in mapDispatchToProps, because React Router's history itself isn't to do with `Dispatch` (I'm not using `react-router-redux`). I mean, `mapDispatchToProps` seems to be dealing with Redux's actions, not anything else. Am I overthinking?

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner approach might be to use React Router's `<Redirect>`:

```
class PostContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (userJustAddedAPostRightNow === true) {
      return <Redirect to='/posts' />
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Post onSubmit={addPost}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(null, { addPost })(PostContainer);
```

`addPost` would trigger a change of state if successful. It should change`userJustAddedAPostRightNow` to true, so that you'll be redirected to the posts' page.

To avoid all those nested callbacks you can follow [Nir Kaufman's approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUuic7mEs-s) and handle logic in middlewares:

```
//src/middlewares/post.js
export const newPost = ({dispatch}) => next => action => {
  next(action);

  if (action.type === ADD_POST) {
    dispatch(apiRequest('POST', action.URL, null, ADD_POST_SUCCESS, ADD_POST_ERROR));
    dispatch(showSpinner());
  }
};
```

Then, on success, `ADD_POST_SUCCESS` action would change, via your reducer, the value of `userJustAddedAPostRightNow`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO , you can do a `history.push` even from your dumb components,i.e

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {    
        addPost: (data) => {
            dispatch(addPost(data)).data.then((result) => {
                dispatch(addPostFulfilled(result.data));
                <!-- removed from here -->
            }).catch((error) => {
                dispatch(addPostRejected());
            });
        },      
    }
}
```

Once your `addPostFulFilled` data is done you have the option of doing your `this.history.push('/route')` in your component itself. You can do it any of the lifefcycle methods which is called when the `props` update. 
Perhaps, add it to `componentWillReceiveProps`.

```
class PostContainer extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  /*Added here*/
  if(nextProps.someFlag){ this.props.history.push('/someRoute');
}}
```

Note that the above works only if

1. You are Ok to not track location changes via the `store`.([Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722584/how-to-sync-redux-state-and-url-hash-tag-params/36749963#36749963))
2. You are using `react-router-4` in which case you will be wrapping your connect with `withRouter` which will enable the history object to be present as a prop in the `PostContainer`.
3. Care should be taken to prevent unnecessary rerenders and write necessary logic in `shouldComponentUpdate`.

If the above sounds like a whole lot of gibberish , you can always go with `react-router-redux`'s `push` API which enable pushing new entries in browser history. You can import that in any place of your choice and just push a new route.

Details can be seen here in the [react-router-redux github pages](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) and to quote the docs

> Both push and replace take in a location descriptor, which can be an
>   object describing the URL or a plain string URL. These action creators
>   are also available in one single object as routerActions, which can be
>   used as a convenience when using Redux's bindActionCreators().

So use the `history.push()` inside your mapDispatchToProps directly, or pass them as an prop to be used inside your `PostContainer` react component.

---

Answer (score 0):

In my case after `history.push()` doesn't work directly,

So I found an alternative that, we should reload windows by `window.location.reload();`

It work for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).