# How to use query parameters from a URL in MapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am facing a problem using `mapStateToProps(state, ownProps)` in order to plug query parameters from my URL to the props of my component.

I am trying to use my URL as a `searchState` as suggested by Dan Abramov answer in this question : [How to sync Redux state and url query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596996/how-to-sync-redux-state-and-url-query-params)

The problem is, I cam not able to access query params from `ownProps`.

My URL is, for example : http://localhost:3000/courses?language=en&page=3 and I would like to access the page number as a prop.

I think `ownProps` does not work for query parameters (i.e `[...]?language=en&page=3`). I tried this kind of stuff but it does not seem to work :

```
[...]
console.log(props.pageNumber)
[...]
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    pageNumber: ownProps.match.params.page
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea on how I could access my page number as an ownProp coming from my URL ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameters are not part of the `params` in `match.params`.  You have to access them yourself from the `location` and parse them using the browser's `URLSearchParams` or a helper like `qs`.  There's a [demo in the docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters) that might help.

Here's the hook from that demo:

```
// A custom hook that builds on useLocation to parse
// the query string for you.
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}
```

Inside your component, you can access the query parameters with this hook and use them as arguments for a selector function.

```
const query = useQuery();

// query parameters might be `null`
const language = query.get("language") ?? "en";

// they are always `string` instead of `number`
const page = parseInt(query.get("page") ?? "1");

// can use these values to select from the store
const courses = useSelector(selectCourses(language, page))
```

You could parse the `location` in `mapStateToProps` if you wanted to.  But Dan's answer is from 2016 and nowadays React hooks make more sense, in my option at least.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to access query parameters inside `componentDidMount` or any method which runs on mounting of any component by using `this.props.location.search` instead of accessing in `mapStateToProps`.